# Editable 'Select' element

Tags: html, html-select

I would like to have a select element in the form but besides the options in the dropdown, it would be useful to be able to edit it and add new option but not with another input text, I need all in once. Is it possible?

Comment: An editable dropdown is also called a "combobox". Now you know a new google keyword :)

Comment: https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcombobox/jquery-combobox-getting-started.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML combo box with option to type an entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Nothing is impossible. Here's a solution that simply sets the value of a text input whenever the value of the `<select>` changes (rendering has been tested on Firefox and Google Chrome):

```css
.select-editable {position:relative; background-color:white; border:solid grey 1px;  width:120px; height:18px;}
.select-editable select {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; font-size:14px; border:none; width:120px; margin:0;}
.select-editable input {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; padding:1px; font-size:12px; border:none;}
.select-editable select:focus, .select-editable input:focus {outline:none;}
```

```html
<div class="select-editable">
  <select onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="format" value=""/>
</div>
```

***jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwH8A/***

The next example adds the user input to the empty option slot of the `<select>` (thanks to @TomerPeled). It also has a little bit more flexible/variable CSS:

```css
.select-editable {position:relative; width:120px;}
.select-editable > * {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; box-sizing:border-box; outline:none;}
.select-editable select {width:100%;}
.select-editable input {width:calc(100% - 20px); margin:1px; border:none; text-overflow:ellipsis;}
```

```html
<div class="select-editable">
  <select onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
    <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
    <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" oninput="this.previousElementSibling.options[0].value=this.value; this.previousElementSibling.options[0].innerHTML=this.value" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.selectedIndex=0" value="" />
</div>
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pu7cndLv/1/*

---

### DataList

In HTML5 you can also do this with the [`<input>` `list` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdeflist) and [`<datalist>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist):

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
(click once to focus and edit, click again to see option dropdown)
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hrkxebtw/*

But this acts more like an auto-complete list; once you start typing, only the options that contain the typed string are left as suggestions. Depending on what you want to use it for, this may or may not be practical.

[Can I use datalists](https://caniuse.com/datalist) ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a closing tag for that input element?

Comment: Just change `>` to ` />` in `<input list="browsers" name="browsers">` that is `<input list="browsers" name="browsers" />`.

Comment: input is a void element, and as such should not (depending on doctype) have a closing tag (since it cannot have content) http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements

Comment: You have a bug in the implementation: If you choose the 115x175 mm from the list, then insert manually some text - 12222 - then try to choose again 115x175 mm  - nothing will happen - this is due to the fact that the list wasn't changed although the input was changed.

Comment: You can solve the bug I mentioned above by adding onchange="this.previousElementSibling.selectedIndex = -1" to the input element.

Comment: I tested this with IE and Edge too. Works nice.

Comment: There are issues with <datalist>. If you have a very long list, It overflow the browser and captures the area from top to bottom on the screen. The styles to curtail the width and height doesn't work. Tested this behavior on chrome 52.x.

There are issues on firefox too. In summary, <datalist> is not stable yet. So, use datalist only when you have a small and limited number of options. Don't use it for long or dynamic lists.

Comment: Thank you @Arrazas. I used your code as the base to make the dropdown editable only if "Other" is selected. Please [see if this code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tarekahf/t392djx1/) implementation is correct.

Comment: FWIW.  I found that I had to add `display: inline-block` to `select-editable` as otherwise, when resizing the web page, the `select` and `input` fields separate.  Ie, the select/dropdown was on the right side of the web page and the input field had wrapped to the left side.

Answer (score 13):

Similar to answer above but without the absolute positioning:

```
<select style="width: 200px; float: left;" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option> 
</select>
<input style="width: 185px; margin-left: -199px; margin-top: 1px; border: none; float: left;"/>
```

So create a input box and put it over the top of the combobox

Comment: Could be broken by floating - made a bit adjusted version bellow.

Answer (score 7):

```html
A bit more universal <select name="env" style="width: 200px; position:absolute;" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option> 
</select>
<input style="width: 178px; margin-top: 1px; border: none; position:relative; left:1px; margin-right: 25px;" value="123456789012345678901234"/>layout ...
```

Comment: To clarify - text around tags is there to demonstrate, layout around works almost identical to their original counterparts.

Comment: `select` tag is a separate window created by OS, always on top?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers, here is a first draft for usage with knockout:

**Usage**

```
      <div data-bind="editableSelect: {options: optionsObservable, value: nameObservable}"></div>
```

**Knockout data binding**

```
composition.addBindingHandler('editableSelect',
  {
    init: function(hostElement, valueAccessor) {

      var optionsObservable = getOptionsObservable();
      var valueObservable = getValueObservable();

      var $editableSelect = $(hostElement);
      $editableSelect.addClass('select-editable');

      var editableSelect = $editableSelect[0];

      var viewModel = new editableSelectViewModel(optionsObservable, valueObservable);
      ko.applyBindingsToNode(editableSelect, { compose: viewModel });

      //tell knockout to not apply bindings twice
      return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };

      function getOptionsObservable() {
        var accessor = valueAccessor();
        return getAttribute(accessor, 'options');
      }

      function getValueObservable() {
        var accessor = valueAccessor();
        return getAttribute(accessor, 'value');
      }
    }
  });
```

**View**

```
<select
  data-bind="options: options, event:{ focus: resetComboBoxValue, change: setTextFieldValue} "
  id="comboBox"
  ></select>
<input
  data-bind="value: value, , event:{ focus: textFieldGotFocus, focusout: textFieldLostFocus}"
  id="textField"
  type="text"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
define([
  'lodash',
  'services/errorHandler'
], function(
  _,
  errorhandler
) {

  var viewModel = function(optionsObservable, valueObservable) {

    var self = this;
    self.options = optionsObservable();
    self.value = valueObservable;
    self.resetComboBoxValue = resetComboBoxValue;
    self.setTextFieldValue = setTextFieldValue;
    self.textFieldGotFocus = textFieldGotFocus;
    self.textFieldLostFocus = textFieldLostFocus;

    function resetComboBoxValue() {
      $('#comboBox').val(null);
    }

    function setTextFieldValue() {
      var selection = $('#comboBox').val();
      self.value(selection);
    }

    function textFieldGotFocus() {
      $('#comboBox').addClass('select-editable-input-focus');

    }

    function textFieldLostFocus() {
      $('#comboBox').removeClass('select-editable-input-focus');
    }

  };
  errorhandler.includeIn(viewModel);

  return viewModel;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.select-editable {

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;padding: 0;
}


.select-editable select {
  outline:0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  height: 29px;
}


.select-editable input {
  outline:0;
  position: relative;
  top: -27px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:90%;
  height: 25px;
  border:none;
}

.select-editable select:focus {
  outline:0;
  border: 1px solid #66afe9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}




.select-editable input:focus {
  outline:0;
}

.select-editable-input-focus {
outline:0;
  border: 1px solid #66afe9 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another sort of workaround might be...

Use the HTML:

```
<input list="myselect" id="myoptions"/>
<datalist id="myselect">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
<option>option 4</option>
</datalist>
```

In Firefox at least a focus followed by a click drops down the list of known valid values as the `<datalist>` elements IFF the field happens to be empty.  Otherwise, one must clear the field to see valid choices as one types in data.  A new value is accepted as typed.  One must handle new values in JS or other to persist them.

This is not perfect, but it suffices for my minimalist needs, so I thought I would share.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Arraxas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141357/editable-select-element/11898865#11898865)'s anwser, I customized the arrow and make the `input` element auto-adaptive to the `select` element, and it looks good on Chrome, Firefox of my Android mobile phone (set `color:transparent` for `select` and some color for `option` to hide text display of the `select` because the `input` and `.combobox div:after` cannot completely cover `select`).

```css
/* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694271/modify-select-so-only-the-first-one-is-gray/41941056#41941056
select option:first-child, */
.combobox select, .combobox select option { color: #000000; }
.combobox select:invalid, .combobox select option[value=""] { color:grey; }

.combobox {position:absolute; left:80px; top:6px;}
.combobox>div { position:relative; font-size:1em; }
.combobox select {
    font-size:inherit; color:transparent;
    padding:0; -moz-appearance:none; -webkit-appearance:none; appearance:none;
    border:1px solid blueviolet;
}
.combobox input {
    position:absolute;top:1px;left:0px; text-overflow:ellipsis;
    box-sizing:border-box; padding:0px; margin:0px; height:calc(100% - 1px); width:calc(100% - 20px);
    border:1px solid blueviolet; border-right:none; border-top:none;
}
.combobox>div:after{
    position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; height:100%; width:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box; content:"▼"; border:1px solid blueviolet; pointer-events:none;
    display:flex; flex-direction:row; align-items:center; justify-content:center;
}
.combobox select:focus, .combobox input:focus {outline:none;}
```

```html
<!-- mandatory benefits/social security/welfare -->
<div class="combobox"><div>
    <select id=MandatoryBenefits onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select ...</option>
        <option value="Pension">Pension %</option>
        <option value="Medical">Medical %</option>
        <option value="Unemployment">Unemployment %</option>
        <option value="Injury">Injury %</option>
        <option value="Maternity">Maternity %</option>
        <option value="Serious Illness">Serious Illness %</option>
        <option value="Housing Fund">Housing Fund %</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.selectedIndex=0"
        oninput="this.previousElementSibling.options[0].value=this.value; this.previousElementSibling.options[0].innerHTML=this.value" />
</div></div>
```

[online demo](https://jsbin.com/tuzodow/edit?html,css,output) (@jsbin)