# How can I create an editable combo box in HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, drop-down-menu

I need to let users select an item from a dropdown list, but also allow them to instead enter any text, even if it doesn't match an item in the list. How can I achieve this on a web page with HTML and Javascript?

The `select` field doesn't let users enter text, and the `input` text field doesn't show the preferred alternatives.

All items must show if the user opens the dropdown, so it can't be a simple auto-complete that only shows matching items.

Comment: You *could* do that on your own (hint: replace the select with your own HTML, that behaves just like a select box), but why inventing the wheel again? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: @Boldewyn: Too bad you didn't put this into an answer. Because this actually is the same control OP is asking for. Demo page actually shows it on ComboBox that acts as normal select + data enter.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Ah, yes. But they added that example more recently than my answer. Back in '10 it was a brand-new widget.

Comment: You'll see some suggestions for this here on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141357/html-editable-select-element/13468539#13468539

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an editable dropdownlist in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264640/how-can-i-create-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML combo box with option to type an entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry)

Comment: W3C sample:  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/combobox/combobox-autocomplete-list.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a script for that:
[Demo](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html),
[Source](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=form_widget_editable_select)

Or another one which works slightly differently:
*link removed (site no longer exists)*

Comment: Thanks! I'm going with the first script.

Comment: @ChristianDavén  Where did you find the source js script in the first link?

Comment: @shapeare, I can't remember, sorry!

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is already answered, a long time ago, but this is for other people that may end up here and are having trouble finding what they need.  I had trouble finding an existing plugin that did exactly what I needed, so I wrote my own jQuery UI plugin to accomplish this task.  It's based on the combobox example on the jQuery UI site.  Hopefully it might help someone.

https://github.com/tmooney3979/jquery.ui.combify

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for an Answer as well, but all I could find was outdated.

This Issue is solved since HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

```
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

If I had not found that, I would have gone with this approach:

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html

Comment: How does the html5 datalist meet the requirement of editable?

Comment: This approach creates a regular input field, in which you can type, but which also shows suggestions while you type (or, when you click in the input field twice when it is empty, once to focus and then a second time, shows the entire list). At least this is how Firefox renders it.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/6hyrjvvb/

Comment: Does not work on FireFox Android browser

Answer (score 3):

You can try my implementation of editable combobox  http://www.zoonman.com/projects/combobox/

Answer (score 2):

I think this will meet your requirements:

https://github.com/RUPOJS/jsCombo

Comment: That's a link only answer, so please add more information, as the page the links is pointing to might vanish.

Comment: thanks buddy this was actually I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget datalist element that good solution for autocomplete function, but not for combobox feature.

css:

```
.combobox {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.combobox select {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="combobox">
    <input type="number" name="" value="" min="" max="" step=""/><br/>
    <select size="3">
        <option value="0"> 0</option>
        <option value="25"> 25</option>
        <option value="40"> 40</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

js (jQuery):

```
$('.combobox').each(function() {
    var
        $input = $(this).find('input'),
        $select = $(this).find('select');
    function hideSelect() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!$select.is(':focus') && !$input.is(':focus')) {
                $select
                    .hide()
                    .css('z-index', 1);
            }
        }, 20);
    }
    $input
        .focusin(function() {
            if (!$select.is(':visible')) {
                $select
                    .outerWidth($input.outerWidth())
                    .show()
                    .css('z-index', 100);
            }
        })
        .focusout(hideSelect)
        .on('input', function() {
            $select.val('');
        });
    $select
        .change(function() {
            $input.val($select.val());
        })
        .focusout(hideSelect);
});
```

This works properly even when you use text input instead of number.

Comment: I have made a little modification for better behaviour when we have more than one comboboxes.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
<div style="position: absolute;top: 32px; left: 430px;" id="outerFilterDiv">
<input name="filterTextField" type="text" id="filterTextField" tabindex="2"  style="width: 140px;
    position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; z-index: 2;border:none;" />
        <div style="position: absolute;" id="filterDropdownDiv">
<select name="filterDropDown" id="filterDropDown" tabindex="1000"
    onchange="DropDownTextToBox(this,'filterTextField');" style="position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 165px;">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-- Select Column Name --</option>
</select>
```

please look at following example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEVXK/)

Comment: The question was how to make combobox editable, you have just overlapped textbox over combobox. This is not the proper solutionI think.

Comment: works perfectly fine when you do not want to use customized buttons. ie to use default set of button provided with browser

Comment: @Vishrant  no, he overlapped a textbox on top of a *dropdown/select* to create a *combination* *box*

Comment: But it doesn't work.  add some <option>s and choose them.  Box does not populate.