# HTML combo box with option to type an entry

Tags: html, combobox

I was under the impression you could type into a combo box besides selecting any values already in the list. However, I can't seem to find info on how to do this. Is there a property I need to add to it to allow typing of text?

Comment: No, you can't do this without some sort of JavaScript or other magic. By itself the `<select>` element can't do that.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I'll look for a jQuery control then.

Comment: Consider [changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry/22805615#22805615) the accepted answer if you think the HTML5 `list` attribute does the job.

Comment: I realise this was years ago, but still I'm puzzled.  What code were you using to create something that is purportedly a combo box?

Comment: @Stewart - Speculating: OP's wording suggests blurring of concept `dropdown` with `combo box`. Presumably used `<select>` with `<option>`, and started with a blank option selected. This has a list of values, and "looks like a combo box"; it just lacks the ability to type into the text area.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Before `datalist` (see note below), you would supply an additional `input` element for people to type in their own option.

```html
<select name="example">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="-">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="other">
```

This mechanism **works in all browsers and requires no JavaScript**.

You could use a little JavaScript to be clever about only showing the `input` if the "Other" option was selected.

## datalist Element

The `datalist` element is intended to provide a better mechanism for this concept. In some browsers, e.g. iOS Safari < 12.2, this was not supported or the implementation had issues. [Check the Can I Use page to see current datalist support](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist).

```html
<input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList">
<datalist id="exampleList">
  <option value="A">  
  <option value="B">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Old school but practical.

Comment: (Chrome on Windows, current version) Be aware that once user starts typing into the text box, that text becomes a **filter** on what items are shown in the drop down. **An unacceptable gotcha:** once an item has been selected, that selection then becomes the filter! In code snippet select "A". Now open dropdown again: ONLY "A" is shown as an option!! That is **not** how a combo box works; it is not useful as-is. AFAIK, fixing this requires JS to CLEAR the text area when open dropdown. (All the other "datalist" answers here have the same fatal flaw, AFAIK.)

Comment: ... in case it isn't clear, I am commenting on the second solution, based on `datalist`.

Answer (score 67):

in HTML, you do this backwards:
You define a text input:

```
<input type="text" list="browsers" />
```

and attach a datalist to it. (note the list attribute of the input).

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: This is not supported in Safari.

Comment: You are right, however I think it will be supported in the near future, since it's part of the HTML5 standard (candidate for now). http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/

Comment: According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/datalist), Safari 8 will not support datalist. 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) says the same.

Comment: And neither does Safari 9.  What's up Apple?

Comment: How does this degrade with Safari?

Comment: seems like it's supported since 2019 Apr

Answer (score 26):

This link can help you:
http://www.scriptol.com/html5/combobox.php

You have two examples. One in html4 and other in html5

HTML5

```html
<input type="text" list="browsers"/>
 <datalist id="browsers">
    <option>Google</option>
    <option>IE9</option>
 </datalist>
```

HTML4

```html
 <input type="text" id="theinput" name="theinput" />
 <select name="thelist" onChange="combo(this, 'theinput')">
   <option>one</option>
   <option>two</option>
   <option>three</option>
 </select>
```

```js
 function combo(thelist, theinput) {
     theinput = document.getElementById(theinput);
     var idx = thelist.selectedIndex;
     var content = thelist.options[idx].innerHTML;
     theinput.value = content;
 }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 6):

The `dojo` example here do not work when applied to existing code in most cases. Therefor I had to find an alternate, found here - hxxp://technologymantrablog.com/how-to-create-a-combo-box-with-text-input-jquery-autocomplete/ (now points to a spam site or worse)

[archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206094457/http://technologymantrablog.com/how-to-create-a-combo-box-with-text-input-jquery-autocomplete/) (not very useful)

Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ze7fgby7/

Comment: This works with Safari, unlike almost everything else out there.

Comment: This is too damn awesome man!.. I would give this 10 upvotes if I could.. Handles everything oh so perfectly..

Comment: The link doesn't work any more unfortunately (do you know of a new link?), but the jsfiddle is very useful.

Comment: @Andre: Sorry, no idea of the new link. Hope the JSFiddle will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

Well it's 2016 and there is still no easy way to do a combo ... sure we have datalist but without safari/ios support it's not really usable. At least we have ES6 .. below is an attempt at a combo class that wraps a div or span, turning it into a combo by putting an input box on top of select and binding the relevant events.

see the code at: https://github.com/kofifus/Combo

(the code relies on the class pattern from https://github.com/kofifus/New)

Creating a combo is easy ! just pass a div to it's constructor:

```js
let mycombo=Combo.New(document.getElementById('myCombo'));
mycombo.options(['first', 'second', 'third']);

mycombo.onchange=function(e, combo) {
  let val=combo.value;
  // let val=this.value; // same as above
  alert(val);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kofifus/New/master/new.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kofifus/Combo/master/combo.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCombo" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Your code snipper do not run in iOS or  Edge via StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

This one is much smaller, doesn't require jquery and works better in safari.
https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill/

Check the issues for the modification to add a downarrow.
https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill/issues

Answer (score 3):

My solution is very simple, looks exactly like a native editable combobox and yet works even in IE6 (some answers here require a lot of code or external libraries and the result is so so, e.g. the text in the textbox goes behind the dropdown icon of the combobox' part or it doesn't look like an editable combobox at all).

The point is to clip the combobox only the dropdown icon to be visible above the textbox. And the textbox is wide a bit underneath the combobox' part, so you don't see its right end - visually continues with the combobox: https://jsfiddle.net/dLsx0c5y/2/

```
select#programmoduleselect
{
    clip: rect(auto auto auto 331px);
    width: 351px;
    height: 23px;
    z-index: 101; 
    position: absolute;
}

input#programmodule
{
    width: 328px;
    height: 17px;
}

<table><tr>
<th>Programm / Modul:</th>
<td>
    <select id="programmoduleselect"
        onchange="var textbox = document.getElementById('programmodule'); textbox.value = (this.selectedIndex == -1 ? '' : this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); textbox.select(); fireEvent2(textbox, 'change');"
        onclick="this.selectedIndex = -1;">
        <option value=RFEM>RFEM</option>
        <option value=RSTAB>RSTAB</option>
        <option value=STAHL>STAHL</option>
        <option value=BETON>BETON</option>
        <option value=BGDK>BGDK</option>
    </select>
    <input name="programmodule" id="programmodule" value="" autocomplete="off"
        onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;" />
</td>
</tr></table>
```

(Used originally e.g. here, but don't send the form: old.dlubal.com/WishedFeatures.aspx )

EDIT: The styles need to be a bit different for macOS: Ch is ok, for FF increase the combobox' height, Safari and Opera ignore the combobox' height so increase their font size (has an upper limit, so then decrease the textbox' height a bit): https://i.stack.imgur.com/efQ9i.png

Comment: This worked very well for me not having to worry about browser differences

Answer (score 1):

Given that the HTML datalist tag is still not fully supported, an alternate approach that I used is the [Dojo Toolkit ComboBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html). It was easier to implement and better documented than other options I've explored. It also plays nicely with existing frameworks. In my case, I added this combobox to an existing website that's based on Codeigniter and Bootstrap with no problems You just need to be sure to apply the Dojo theme (e.g. class="claro") to the combo's parent element instead of the body tag to avoid styling conflicts.

First, include the CSS for one of the Dojo themes (such as 'Claro'). It's important that the CSS file is included prior to the JS files below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
```

Next, include jQuery and Dojo Toolkit via CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Next, you can just follow [Dojo's sample code](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html) or use the sample below to get a working combobox.

```
<body>
    <!-- Dojo Dijit ComboBox with 'Claro' theme -->
    <div class="claro"><input id="item_name_1" class=""/></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //In this example, dataStore is simply an array of JSON-encoded id/name pairs
            dataStore = [{"id":"43","name":"Domain Name Renewal"},{"id":"42","name":"Hosting Renewal"}];

            require(
                [ "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"], 
                function (Memory, ComboBox) {
                    var stateStore = new Memory({
                        data: dataStore
                    });

                    var combo = new ComboBox({
                        id: "item_name_1",
                        name: "desc_1",
                        store: stateStore,
                        searchAttr: "name"},                        
                        "item_name_1"
                        ).startup();

                });

        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers were satisfying, largely because the UI still looks bad. I found [this](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select), which looks good and is very close to being perfect as well as customizable.

A full list of examples and options and such can be found [here](http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select), but here's a basic demo:

```js
$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-editable-select@2.2.5/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-editable-select@2.2.5/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="editable-select">
 <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
 <option>Audi</option>
 <option>BMW</option>
 <option>Citroen</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @maqs I looked around a lot when I found this library, and **none** of the other libraries or solutions out there were full solutions that functioned well and looked the same regardless of platform. On some common platforms, many solutions looked absolutely terrible.

Comment: @maqs The reason it's not so simple of a task is because HTML doesn't support it out of the box and so every aspect of it from the looks to the functionality to the event handling and configuration has to be sort of hacked together to work around HTML's limitations.

Answer (score -1):

Look at ComboBox or Combo on this site: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#

Comment: That's not a real combo box, because you can't add new data.

Comment: Combo on that page is worse than the standard html select.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#selectnumber').change(function(){
                alert('.val() = ' + $('#selectnumber').val() + '  AND  html() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').html() + '  AND .text() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').text());
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
       <div>
        <select id="selectnumber">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>

    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: Click to see OutPut Screen]

Thanks...:)

Comment: Always a good idea to include some detail or explanation for why your answer works.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!