# how to create a textbox in a list (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a list in HTML (single selection) which will have -

1. A textbox to enter text.
2. List of options from which user can select any one option.

What I want is - **a list with a textbox as an option.**

The basic list syntax in HTML goes like -

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

while the basic textbox syntax in HTML goes like -

```
<input type="textbox" name="first">
```

Kindly help, as nesting the textbox syntax inside the list syntax doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Aside from building a custom select list, the `<option>` in a `select` cannot do that. They can only have text in them

Comment: You won't be able to directly add an input as an option in a select. The solution depends of your needs. You propose options to a user but you want him to be able to enter a custom value, isn't it ?

Comment: `type="textbox"` doesn't appear to be a valid type for `<input>`.

Comment: @OlivierH >> Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Jamie Read >> Ok, then how to build such a list?

Comment: See this existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry

Comment: You can use http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: @Dan>> I want the user to manually enter the data when the textbox is selected (not by choosing any option which will fill the data into the textbox  automatically). Plus the textbox has to be in the list.

Comment: @RajarshiSarkar>> In plain HTML you can't do it. You might be able to do it with a custom control written and installed on the server, or there might be a JS library out there that can do it. Much like RUJordan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it this way with a standard select element.

You can use UI javascript librairies to use custom controls. What you need here is generally called an **autocomplete**.

This control is a mix between a combobox and a text input. You can select an option with mouse as you would do with a classic select, but you are also able to use keyboard to filter results.

[Here is an example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding) of what I'm talking about. This is the *jQuery UI* library's demos page. You can see here an autocomplete in action. The demo I linked has no clickable button to display the options list. Have a look at combobox demo.

Playing with this, you will be able to have a combobox in which you will be able to type custom values.

There is many libraries like this one available on the net. [Here is a wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#GUI-related_.28Widget_libraries.29).

Comment: The combobox demo (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) was infact helpful. Thanks.