# HTML input tag function + select tag function?

Tags: javascript, html

**My Question**

I searched to figure out my question but I couldn't figure out.

I wonder if it is any way to build select which you even can write like input(type=text). For example, You can select one option from select list or you can write on it without selecting any.

I want to mix functions of two below in **one input**.

```
<select>
    <option value=1>A</option>
    <option value=2>B</option>
</select>

<input type="text">
```

you can select A or B by select function but if you don't find what you want  from select, you can write for example C instead.

---

**Conclusion**

I could find refereces for my question **when I search with keyword "html combo"** My problem was I tried to find with wrong keyword!

simiply, (I mixed HTML5 syntax and HTML4 syntax, i think)

```
<input type="text" list="test">
<datalist id="test">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>world!</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: "Combo box" is the usual term for such a control. HTML doesn't do it natively, but you can simulate it. There are a few around, including jQuery plugins (I know you didn't tag your question with "jQuery", but you could have a look at the plugin code), and probably some standalone ones.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry

Comment: There are several jquery plugins for this: https://select2.github.io -- http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js -- https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen

Comment: oh Thanks, I could find answer for my question easily with keyword 'html combo box'. I figured out!

Comment: The other term that might help you track down an solution is "typeahead", something like [awesomplete](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML combo box with option to type an entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry)

Comment: @Rob Yes, it is duplicate of the question definitely. My problem was that I tried to find with wrong keyword. I could get reference by searching combo box. Thank you!

Comment: @Jayground, check here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default you can find many examples

Comment: @HakanKose Thank you for the link! It is not related to my question exactly but it is good information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then this is the answer

```html
<input type="text" list="test">
<datalist id="test">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>world!</option>
</datalist>
```