# Jquery autocomplete combo box/selectbox using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I want to ask, has someone ever created autocomplete using combo box / select box with code igniter?

I've tried but only managed to use autocomplete for 2 input text but I have another idea to create autocomplete with text combined with combo box. I've do created that but I have trouble my autocomplete in the text is successful but in the combo box does not work only show empty option. can someone help me? this is my source code

My Table : i probably using 2 table for autocomplete : 1. tb_produk and 2. tb_kategori_produk

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2g7v.jpg | 2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkk5t.jpg

My Controller : user.php

```
public function request_produk(){ //used for calling view

    $data["kateprod"] = $this->db->where("f_status_kategori_produk","1")
                            ->get("tb_kategori_produk")->result_array();
    $this->theme->panel('user/v_request',$data);
}

public function mesin() //user for jquery called data
{
    $keyword = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = $this->db->from('tb_produk')->join('tb_kategori_produk','tb_kategori_produk.f_id_kategori_produk=tb_produk.f_kategori_produk')->like('f_nama_produk',$keyword)->get();  

    foreach($data->result() as $row)
    {
        $arr['query'] = $keyword;
        $arr['suggestions'][] = array(
            'value' =>$row->f_nama_produk,
            'idpro' =>$row->f_id_produk,
            'idkate' =>$row->f_id_kategori_produk,
            'kategori'=>$row->f_nama_kategori_produk

        );
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

My Controller : v_request.php

```
<div id="content">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var site = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
        $(function() {
            $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
                serviceUrl: site+"/user/mesin",
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                      $("#v_idproduk").val(""+suggestion.idpro);
                      $("#v_kategori").val(""+suggestion.kategori);
                      $("#v_idkategori").val(""+suggestion.idkate);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php $id = $this->session->userdata('f_id_user'); 
    <input type="hidden" name="dt[f_id_user]" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('f_id_user'); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="v_idproduk" name="dt[f_id_produk]">
    <input type="hidden" id="v_idkategori" name="dt[f_kategori_produk]">

    <div class="form-group br-form"> <!-- This form group i used to autocomplete text -->
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Nama Mesin</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="search" class="autocomplete form-control" id="autocomplete1" name="nama_mesin" required/>
         </div>
     </div><br><br>

     <div class="form-group br-form"> <!-- This form group i used to autocomplete combo box-->
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">Kategori Mesin</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10">    
            <select id="v_kategori" name="dt[f_kategori_produk]" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="">---Harap Pilih---</option>
                <?php foreach ($kateprod as $key) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$key['f_id_kategori_produk']?>" id="v_kategori"><?php echo $key["f_nama_kategori_produk"];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
     </div><br>
```

This is my demo

```
https://streamable.com/wvn25
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry

Comment: thanks vickel for the answer. But i've different issue with your link shared. i've a demo and you can watch it. https://streamable.com/wvn25