# How to implement autocomplete with array values in java-script on asp.net text box,

Tags: javascript, asp.net, autocomplete, textbox

Need to create an asp.net text-box control with autocomplete feature (like intelli sense) with JavaScript, auto complete values source should be an array.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MovieName"  runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>

var ArrayMovies = ["KGF", "HarrayPotter", "Mad Max", "God Father", "Baby Driver", "IT", "Haunted House"];
```

Please give me the solution in details since i'm complete fresher to javascript.

Comment: You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry) link you can use javascript to create list

Comment: The mentioned link does not explain with asp.net textbox control