# Insert data that doesnt exist from selectbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backend

I would want a select box that can insert data if the data typed doesn't exist in the DB, could anyone help me, please?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Catégorie</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="category" required>
        <?php
        $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_category");
        $select->execute();
        while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row)
        ?>
            <option><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry).

Answer (score 0):

Use select2 plugging. It's facilitated to search and add new value which is not in dropdowns.

Click [here](https://select2.org/tagging) Select2

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Catégorie</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="category" required id="category">
        <?php
        $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_category");
        $select->execute();
        while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row)
        ?>
            <option><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
$("#category").select2({
   tags: true
 });
```