# Editable combo box in Redux-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

Something to similar with this thread: [How can I create an editable combo box in HTML/Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052130/how-can-i-create-an-editable-combo-box-in-html-javascript)

Is it possible to have a combo-box form in Redux-Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<Field
    options={[
      {value: 1, text: 'Option1'},
      {value: 2, text: 'Option2'}
    ]}
    component={Select}
    label="My select question"
    className="col-md-6"
  />

const Select = ({input, options, label, error}) => {
  if (error && error.length > 0) {
    className += " " + 'has-error'
  }
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {label && <label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</label>}
        <select {...input} >
          {options.map(function (option, i) {
            return (
              <option
                value={option.value}
                key={i}
              >
                {option.text}
              </option>)
          })}
        </select>
        {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```