# Modify Select So Only The First One Is Gray

Tags: html, css

I have a `select` element and am using the first `option` as the title of the select field. I am wondering if there is a way to gray out the text inside the `select` field when the first option is selected. Can this only be done in JS, or is there a CSS solution?

I have tried changing the style of the first `option` but that only changes the colour of the text when I activate the dropdown menu.

```
<select>
  <option>Please select your favourite fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Here is a more modern solution so it's not specific to the first option, but rather an *invalid* option and requires no JS to show only the title/placeholder option as grey whereas the rest appear normal.

```css
select,
select option {
  color: #000000;
}

select:invalid,
select option[value=""] {
  color: #999999;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

/*Added for browser compatibility*/
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
    Invalid option cannot be selected and is hidden from the user in the dropdown.
    <select required>
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Please select your favourite fruit</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label>
    Invalid option cannot be selected, but is not hidden from the user in the dropdown.
    <select required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please select your favourite fruit</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label>
    Invalid option can be selected and is not hidden from the user in the dropdown.
    <select required>
      <option value="" selected>Please select your favourite fruit</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

The `:invalid` selector on the select only works on an option
if the select box is required *and* the selected option's value is empty,
so you can style it as you would a text box's placeholder text.

Setting it to `disabled` prevents the user from selecting it in the select's options,
and setting it to `hidden` hides it from the select's options.

Here is my [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/TessaWatkins/pen/bwymaY) that explores additional select box styles and shows this one in action on a light background.

Comment: `:invalid` makes all option grey if the value is empty. This is not a clean solution.

Comment: @jstice4all can you show me the HTML and CSS you're using? In my CodePen demo I linked to in the answer, it does not cause all of the options to appear grey when they are selected. Only the invalid option appears grey when selected.

Comment: Ah, I saw what you mean. When you use just <option>text</option> without setting the value="", they also appeared grey in the drop-down. I've updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, Tessa! Since my answer is almost 5 years old and this one is much better to solve the problem and uses only CSS, I'm gonna edit mine and point to this one.

Comment: @AllanRaquin Did you try the CodePen demo in the same browser/OS? http://codepen.io/TessaWatkins/pen/bwymaY

Comment: @Tessa Yes I tried and found that the normalize.css is absolutely necessary to make it works. Something is probably missing in the in the answer's stylesheet to make it work as a standalone solution. But didn't find what :/

Comment: Ah, I see normalize.css includes "[hidden], template{ display: none; }", which is why the first option with the "hidden" attribute would not appear, but it's also in my user agent sylesheet as "option[Attributes Style]", so perhaps that browser doesn't include that CSS by default. Good catch! Did the font still appear as grey? Or was it that it just wasn't being hidden?

Comment: @AllanRaquin I added that CSS to the answer snippet. Try again and let me know if that resolved your problem.

Comment: @Tessa First, thanks for your efforts ! In fact the first option was already hidden in the previous version. It's my fault I didn't specified what wasn't working, the problem is the color. In the snippet it's always set to black, even with in the new version. But it works in the codepen with the 2 last select, (and only with the normalize). Here the simplified version of the working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opdxZE?editors=1100 (so still with the normalize.css)

Comment: Wasn't able to get the option[value=""] to work all the way. (Using a dark background) In the options list the text is grey, but the selected option color is still white even when it's the intended place holder. I have select set to white, and select option set to white, then with option[value=""] set to grey below both of them in the style sheet. Select select is still white (using vanilla css)

Comment: @ZackPlauché If you're doing a lot of style customization with a select field, especially with the drop-down menu's appearance, I recommend using an HTML/JS alternative to the native element because browsers and mobile devices do not display them consistently.

Comment: @Tessa that makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @ZackPlauché No problem! It can be quite frustrating trying to style a select field and make it appear consistent in all browsers/devices. I think my phone doesn't even display the drop-down, it just pulls the options up in it's own UI scroll wheel at the bottom. No CSS on the `option` element is going to change that!

Comment: In Safari I notice the top example doesn't do the hiding. Seems it's just a fun safari inconsistency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025961/338265

Comment: You'll want to add :not(:disabled) to the 'select option' in the CSS if you have other disabled options besides the first

Comment: FOR ANGULAR USERS: This solution worked, but you have to adapt it slightly. Instead of using `:invalid` you have to use `.ng-invalid` at the end of the element. Then you don't even need the `[value=""]` specification.

Comment: why it does not work here ? https://codepen.io/sandeshsapkota/pen/qBYOVEQ @AuRise

Comment: @SandeshSapkota because in your CSS, you've defined them both as red

Answer (score 42):

### September 2017 edit

You should take a look at [Tessa's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941056/1087846), since it's CSS only and much better now! This answer is almost 5 years old now, so things have changed a bit. I'm keeping the original answer just for reference.

### Original answer

I am closer to what you need:

You need to gray the entire SELECT (so that when it's closed, it is gray), then "un-gray" all the OPTION's (put them black) and gray the first-child. Something like this:

**CSS**

```
select
{
    color: #ccc;
}
option
{
    color: #000;
}
option:first-child
{
    color: #ccc;
}
```

***EDIT*** 
So the edited code is:

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="changeMe(this)">
  <option selected disabled>Please select your favourite fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeMe(sel)
    {
      sel.style.color = "#000";              
    }
</script>
```

I've update jsFiddle. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/s5Xy2/5/
​

Notice that I've also changed the HTML part, because I think you want to use the "disabled"  attribute (and because of that, you'll have to add the "selected" attribute also).

If you still want the pure CSS code, it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/s5Xy2/4/

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the furthest you can go with pure CSS. I'll consider if it is worth using Javascript to achieve a visual effect. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually using JS to achieve what you want won't add much more complexity. I'll throw you an example in a couple of minutes...

Comment: @vsync Well, the OP asked «Can this only be done in JS, or is there a CSS solution?» to which I gave the most approximate CSS-only solution I know. 
Then (and it's labeled as an edit), I also gave him a minimal JS solution. 
If you find a better, CSS-only solution, please do tell me. :)

Comment: Can't select first (gray) item back after selecting some other item in JS example. All items are gray when selected in CSS example.

Comment: Worked for me, but throws an exception as soon as you select a valid item:  ReferenceError: changeMe is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: @wickedchild Take a look at where you defined the `changeMe` function. It's probably defined in an incorrect place and it's not on the global scope. Did you take a look at the jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 5):

Inspired from Fábio Silva's solution, a very cool solution using **AngularJS**:

```
select {
  color: #ccc;
}
option {
  color: #aaa;
}
option:first-child {
  color: #ccc;
}
select.ng-dirty {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code to my code:

```
<select id="drop">
  <option>Please select your favourite fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<style type="text/css">
#drop :first-child
{
color:gray;
}
</style>
```

This code sets the first item color to gray.

Comment: This only grays out the first child when you open/activate the dropdown. I think that @icu222much wants it to be grayed, even with the dropdown closed (but only when the first item is selected)

Comment: Hey man this code worked on IE , for complete do he what need use java script , i ask him for update answer...

Comment: @MahdiParsa I am looking for a non javascript/jQuery solution.

Comment: @FábioSilva You are correct. I want the first select option be gray even when the dropdown is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2018 version that combines some of the other answers and a bit of my own js. There does not seem to be a solution that works w/o javascript if you want the first element gray when it is closed.

```js
var grayout = document.getElementsByClassName('grayout');

var grayOutSelect = function() {
    if ( this.value === "" ) {
        this.classList.add('gray');
    } else {
        this.classList.remove('gray');
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < grayout.length; i++) {
    grayout[i].addEventListener('change', grayOutSelect);
    if ( grayout[i].value === "" ) {
        grayout[i].classList.add('gray');
    } else {
        grayout[i].classList.remove('gray');
    }
}
```

```css
select {
  color: #333;
}
select.gray {
  color: #aaa;
}

/* Optional styles for when the select is open. Doesn't work on all browsers */
option {
  color: black;
}
.grayout option:first-child {
  color: gray;
}


/* Extra / just to make the demo look nice */
body {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
select {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 60px 5px 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Feather-arrows-chevron-down.svg');
  background-position: 97% center;
  background-position: right 8px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-padding-end: 30px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 8px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  font-size: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: border 300ms;
}
```

```html
<p>main example</p>
<p>
  <select class="grayout">
    <option value="">Please select your favourite fruit</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>one of the real options is selected</p>
<p>
  <select class="grayout">
    <option value="">Please select your favourite computer</option>
    <option value="apple" selected>Apple</option>
    <option value="c64">Commodore 64</option>
    <option value="gateway2000">Gateway 2000</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>the grayout style is not applied here</p>
<p>
  <select>
    <option value="">Please select your favourite insult</option>
    <option value="jerk">Jerk</option>
    <option value="ahole">A**hole</option>
    <option value="shakespeare">Thou damned and luxurious mountain goat</option>
  </select>
</p>
```