# option.style.display = "none" not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

This is the example I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/4suwY/5/

HTML:

```
<select id="asd">
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>I'M THE CHOSEN ONE</option>
    <option>asd</option>
    <option>wer</option>
    <option>qwe</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("asd");
var optnz = sel.getElementsByTagName("option")[1];
sel.value = optnz.value;
optnz.style.display = "none";
```

As you can see, it works in chrome, but it does not work in safari.. What it should do, is hide the "I'M THE CHOSEN ONE" option when you click the dropdown menu..

This is another test I made: http://jsfiddle.net/4suwY/11/

Same HTML, this is the JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("asd");
var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.innerHTML = "YAYA";
opt.value = "YAYA";
sel.appendChild(opt);
sel.value = "YAYA";
opt.style.display = "none";
```

Anyway, what I need to do is display an option as selected (current), and hide to the user when the dropdown menu is opened, so he can't choose it.

Any suggestion / workaround? I don't see any error. What's wrong with Safari? Should I change approach? Jquery seems not to help.

---

EDITS:

I need to hide the options in the dropdownmenu, but at the same time I need to show this option "value" as the selected value! For example, the "closed" dropdown will show the value "I'M THE CHOSEN ONE", but if I click and open the menu, the only visible options will be "hello, asd, wer, qwe"..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't toggle display on `<option>` elements in Safari (or IE, for that matter). This is part of a long and inconsistent tradition with Safari restricting CSS styling functionality on form elements, believing the visual language of interactive elements should be consistent with the OS (no point trying to find a rationale for IE's failings).

Your only options are either to remove it (and re-append it later), or to set it to `optnz.disabled = true`. Sorry for the bad news!

Comment: That saved my day

Comment: Or use `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @JDrake visibility: hidden does not work

Comment: display: none; on <ul> element works fine for me on mobile but not laptop