# nth-child does not work in Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm trying following CSS, it works in Firefox and Chrome but does not work in the Safari (5.1). I have checked Safari supports nth-child. What I'm doing wrong?

**CSS:**

```
option:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Kv9tj/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

You can always use: nth-of-type(2) .

Browser support for :nth-of-type is fairly decent... Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.5+, Chrome 2+, Safari 3.1+, IE 9+.

I hope this will help you!!!

Comment: I was having similar issues with displaying :nth-childs as none, and changing it to :nth-of-type cleared it right up on Safari mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not `nth-child`, but `display: none` on `option`.
For example, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025961/39068 (to a similar question).

It says that you can not set `display: none` on `option` in Safari or IE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know any alternative solution to remove some option values using CSS only in the safari?

Comment: Personally I do not know, but it might be impossible to do without JS if the browser does not support it.