# HTML Select Option Need to Be Highlighted

Tags: html, css

I am creating an HTML Drop-down. Here is My Code

http://jsfiddle.net/dineshk/u47xjqLv/

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option class="first"  style="display:none;">HH</option>  
    <option class="green">Hello</option> 
    <option>Magazine</option>         

</select>
```

I have Given first `Option` to `Display:none` So that it should not show in the Drop Down List. Thats Working. Cool !!!!, But I am not able to Give color for this first `Option` Hence it is the Heading of the  Drop Down, Please Help me to find the Answer

Comment: be careful with `display:none` as it may not work in all browsers. I've asked a similar question a while ago, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025555/js-option-style-display-none-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-safari)

Comment: You can't style <option> items. Some attributes work but it's not portable at all. You'd better to consider them as _untouchable_ plain text items and go with something else if you need more flexibility (with all its drawbacks...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

You can set the colour on the `select` and the `option` giving you a colour for the dropdown and for the placeholder text (HH).

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u47xjqLv/1/)

**Example**

```
select {
  color: red;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}
```

### Option 2

If the first option (Hello) is purely a heading and you do not want it to be selected, then you should set it to `disabled`.  You can then style this accordingly.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u47xjqLv/2/)

**Example**

```
<select>
  <option class="first"  style="display:none;">HH</option>  
  <option disabled class="green">Hello</option> 
  <option>Magazine</option>         
</select>

select option[disabled] {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Brother, It was working ..Previous answer...Now Y changed again http://jsfiddle.net/u47xjqLv/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try it also-

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/u47xjqLv/3/)</kbd>

*css:-*

```
option:nth-child(2){color:red}
```