# How can I let the disable option being bold and black at select html?

Tags: html, css, html-select, optgroup

The system default selects the "Please Select" option and it is disable to select.
Now the option is gray.
Can I bold it and let the color is black?

Thank you.

```
 <select id="commentType" name="commentType" required="true" >
        
                                            <option value="Please Select" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
                                            <option value="Bonus Point">Bonus Point</option>
                                            <option value="Car Park">Car Park</option>
                                            <option value="Gift">Gift</option>
                                            <option value="Promotion">Promotion</option>
                                            <option value="Technical Support">Technical Support</option>
                                            <option value="Others">Others</option>
        
    </select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnsCr.png)

Comment: You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13708240/1706467) one to set style for first option.

Comment: I want the effect same like <optgroup selected> but <optgroup> cannot be selected so how can I do that?

Comment: I confused a little, It's better to share your specific code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this..**

```html
<select id="commentType" name="commentType" required="true">

  <option value="Please Select" disabled selected style="font-weight:bold;color:black">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Bonus Point">Bonus Point</option>
  <option value="Car Park">Car Park</option>
  <option value="Gift">Gift</option>
  <option value="Promotion">Promotion</option>
  <option value="Technical Support">Technical Support</option>
  <option value="Others">Others</option>

</select>
```