# Why is the :invalid CSS selector required for this select list style to work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I want the first `option` in a `select` to be shown as grey. I found a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941056/9971404).

The important bits:

```css
/* fails */
.select1 option[value=""] {
  color: #999999;
}

/* works */
.select2:invalid,
.select2 option[value=""] {
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div>Fails:</div>
<select class="select1">
  <option value="" selected>Select a fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>

<div>Works:</div>
<select class="select2" required>
  <option value="" selected>Select a fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Run the demo and you'll see the first example fails, while the second example works.

I'd expect the CSS selector `.select2:invalid, .select2 option[value=""]` to mean "either-or"; yet it fails without the leading `.select2:invalid,`.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your confusion is due to a number of misunderstandings here. Your understanding of a CSS selector having a comma in it meaning "either-or" *is* correct, but I think that's the only thing you got right.

First, the option elements and the select element are two different things; what you see on the dropdown box is the `<select>` element, not the currently-chosen `<option>` element... to view the `<option>` elements, you need to *activate* the select element to show the options... notice how you see the select element value *and* the same value as one of the options when you do that?

Second, the CSS selector for your first dropdown box is `.select1 option[value=""]`. This is styling *only the option*, not the select element itself. If you click on the first select element and then hover over the Apple or Banana options, you'll see the "Select a fruit" option is greyed out. I repeat, the  is greyed out... because that's what your selector says to apply the style to.

The second dropdown box has the same selector (but for `.select2`)... which means the options will still be greyed out where appropriate. **But** it also has `.select2:invalid`, which is the first part of the kicker. `.select2:invalid` applies to the `<select>` element, not the options... and occurs whenever the currently-selected option is an invalid one.

How it *knows* which ones are invalid is the second part of the kicker: you have the `required` attribute on the second `<select>` element, but not on the first one. Because the second element has `required` on it, it knows that it is "invalid" unless it has an option with a *non-empty* value selected.

I should also probably explain at this point that the value of an `<option>` is whatever is in the `value=""` attribute by default; if the `value=""` attribute is not declared, then the contents of the `<option>` element are used. So the values for your working dropdown box are `empty`, `Apple`, and `Banana`. The `empty` value is invalid, because you have the `required` attribute set on the dropdown box.

---

So in summation, as you were perhaps close to discovering, it is *both* the `.select2:invalid` selector *and* the `.select2 option[value=""]` that are needed, **but not just that**; you *also* need the `required` attribute on the `<select>` element for both of those 'validation'-based selectors to work.

Comment: I'm an old hand at html, but didn't consider the distinction between the styling of the select itself, and the styling of the first option. I assumed there was some overlap between the two, but obviously they are styled separately - which makes sense now that you've described it in detail. We learn something new every day. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, my confusion was compounded by the fact that it doesn't render that way in Firefox (the grey item is not grey). I just checked in Chromium and it's indeed rendered as you've described.

Comment: @Ionix Hmm, I use Firefox and it's grey for me. The behavior is identical between the two (except that the active/hovered option in Firefox is just black text whereas in Chrome it highlights the option in blue).

Answer (score 0):

In your first select option color is grey but when it show in select because select color is black it's showing black color

```
.select1,
.select1 option[value=""]{
  color: #999999;
}
```

give both select and option value the color you want and your option give other color like this. It will solve your problem

```
.select1 option{
  color: black;
}
```

```css
/* fails */
.select1,
.select1 option[value=""]{
  color: #999999;
}

.select1 option{
  color: black;
}


/* works */
.select2:invalid,
.select2 option[value=""] {
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div>Fails:</div>
<select class="select1">
  <option value="" selected>Select a fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>

<div>Works:</div>
<select class="select2" required>
  <option value="" selected>Select a fruit</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```