# Show all options of datalist on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onfocus, html-datalist

Is there any way to show all options of datalist on focus? I need to show all the options even after a key press.

```
<form action="" method="get">
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
 <datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
 </datalist>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jffasna/9yfm7wne/)

PS: This is not same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141357) question. My datalist options are generated dynamically using jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editable 'Select' element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141357/editable-select-element)

Comment: Use a javascript select script instead. datalist filters based on input by default

Comment: select script? Is it a library or what?

Comment: A similar question was later answered here: [How can I make a browser display all datalist options when a default value is set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478727/how-can-i-make-a-browser-display-all-datalist-options-when-a-default-value-is-se)

Comment: Just a word of caution the datalist element is not widely supported across all browsers. [http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist)

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to implement searchable input field there's a lot of jquery plugin for it.
ex. https://select2.github.io or https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: they answered on it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187207/1919821 It help me

Answer (score -2):

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
  $(this).val('');
});
```

try this this will work

Comment: Please add more information as why your code will work to help others learn.

Comment: `click` is not `focus`. Setting `value` on focus does nothing. List appears on `click` by default.