# input + datalist, default value, reset on select?

Tags: jquery, html, html-datalist

I'm using a `<datalist>` to allow selection of an option, yet still allow type-in values. Here's what I mean:

```
<input list="cities" name="city">
<datalist id="cities">
    <option value="Portland">
    <option value="San Francisco">
</datalist>
```

Once a city is chosen, opening the dropdown only shows that city unless I manually hit backspace to clear it. I thought I might fix that with jquery like this:

```
$('input[name=city]').click(function() {
  $('input[name=city]').empty();
});
```

That's great, but it doesn't work. [I've seen in other examples how to remove a 'selected' flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) ([here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box)), but I don't see that it applies to a `<datalist>`.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tedder/ekaLc64t/2/

Comment: tedder42, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37479774/854222

Comment: @JoelHernandez yeah, that did it. Too bad the other one wasn't accepted. If you leave an answer here I'll accept it. [here's my completed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tedder/ekaLc64t/8/).

Comment: tedder42, the answer was not mine. It's better to give credit to the original author. Have a great day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but try to change the code to:

```
  $('input[name=city]').focusin(function() {
    $('input[name=city]').val('');
  });
  $('#xx').click(function() {
    $('input[name=city]').val('');

  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ekaLc64t/9/

Comment: I like it. `focusin` is better than `click`.