# To show datalist on enter key at an input type text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an input text field which has list of items as datalist. I want to show the list of items if someone navigate to the field by using tab and then press enter key.

I tried triggering click(), but didn't work.

```
<input type='text' list='fruits'>
<datalist id='fruits'>
 <option>Apple</option>
 <option>Orange</option>
 <option>Grape</option>
</datalist>
```

script;

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
  $(this).click();
 }
});
```

Any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: the question is not clear enough, what are you trying to achieve? which jQuery Version you use?

Comment: Please clarify:   in modern browsers, a datalist paired to input with `list=` will auto show when you focus the input:  https://jsfiddle.net/c18kmL20/1/   Also, your question is a little unclear as it states *"on enter key"* (which I read as press enter when in the input and matches your code attempt) but also *"navigate to the field by using tab and enter key*" - so navigate with tab would :focus, but navigate with enter key?   Exactly what problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: navigate to the input field (focus) using tab. Focus is not showing the list. SO I tried showing the list on enter press. Neither of them working

Comment: Classic XY problem.   Does it show the list on the fiddle I provided above?

Comment: In the fiddle also I couldn't see the list on focus using tab.

Comment: Now that's useful information (suprisingly).  I was getting it because I was clicking in the input to give it focus (despite you saying using tab).  I've added another input to the fiddle to show it doesn't show on tab.  https://jsfiddle.net/vLgpr16t/   The (windows) *standard* way to show a drop down (ye-olde winforms, `<select>` and now `<datalist>`) is to use alt-cursor-down when the input has focus.  Enter *may* cause any `<form>` to submit, so generally would be a bad idea.

Comment: Given the way the datalist (in Chrome at least, I believe it's different for every browser), a simple `.show()` (or opacity) isn't going to cut it.  You'll need to treat the datalist as a div and reposition it and style it with css, [this answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67399181/2181514) (which is for a different question so does additional functionality).  In which case, you might as well use a `div` and add all the tedious keyboard handling yourself - or a third party plugin such as [tag:select2].

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `css` selector called [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) for that.

```
<style>
     #fruits {
          opacity: 0;
     }

     #fruits:focus {
          opacity: 1;
     }
</style>
```

Note that you cannot use `display: none;` as default because it makes the element not focusable.