# Unable to edit item after item selection in ng-select angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

I am using `ng-select`

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select
```

npm library in my angular project. it is working with large data without any problem.

But I am unable to edit the selected item and navigation keys are not working inside the input box once the item is selected.

For example I searched **something12** first, then I had to choose **something31**. In this case I can't clear last two characters.
To change the search thing, I have to clear whole text and retype again for new search.

**Versions:**

```
ng-select 2.16.4
angular 7.2.2
```

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) of your working code please

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select try the same in this one.

Comment: It is the default behavior of select that you cannot edit in that, so that you cannot navigate trough charters using keys. For that you need some hack to paste `input`over select and assign its values in `input`. If you need ill provide you with simple `HTML5` solution

Comment: yeah it is the default behaviour but i have to make it work by some way. can you give the solution which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> Pure Html and Css Solution in case you need

**Option 1**

```css
 .select-editable {
     position:relative;
     background-color:white;
     border:solid grey 1px;
     width:120px;
     height:18px;
 }
 .select-editable select {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     font-size:14px;
     border:none;
     width:120px;
     margin:0;
 }
 .select-editable input {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     width:100px;
     padding:1px;
     font-size:12px;
     border:none;
 }
 .select-editable select:focus, .select-editable input:focus {
     outline:none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="select-editable">
    <select onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
        <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
        <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="format" value="" />
</div>
```

**Option 2**

```html
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
(click once to focus and edit, click again to see option dropdown)
```

Last but not Least May be this would help you
[Angular editable dropdown - make editable based on selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619490/angular-editable-dropdown-make-editable-based-on-selected-value)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add:

```
[multiple]="false"
[editableSearchTerm]="true"
to your ng-select
```

after you need to use a custom template for editable item:

```
<ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index" let-search="searchTerm">
   <span class="ng-value-label" >{{item.name}}  {{item.id}}</span>
</ng-template>
```