# Multiply input in form for one attribute in model, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form on which I need to arrange an input field for entering a comment (type string) or select from predefined comments (select fields). How i can do this? Can i write comment into select field from keyboard and save it in db?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1. You can use `[simple_enum][1]` gem to predefined all comment values and then render it in view.  [1]: https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_enum
2. You can create one table and save all the predefined comments and load it through active record query.

Comment: thaks, but i ask how i can give a two ways to set comment in one field? (user can write or select from list)

Answer (score 0):

i find an answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11898865/7437218
example:

```html
<datalist id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</datalist>
```

i can get option for datalist from model with predefined comments