# Adding <textarea> tag inside a <select> tag after clicking an option on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, drop-down-menu, jsx

So basically, I got the following JSX file and I want to have an event handler that listens to an event that is generated after clicking **"Other"** in the manufacturer section. Please find the mentioned option as the last `<option>` tag inside the `<select>` tag with the name "colour", and inside the `<Fragment>` tag. Also, please ignore the OnClick function that is already there; it has no use in this problem.

The event that I want to be generated is quite particular. It should add a text area (or input, not entirely sure) where the "Other" option inside the drop-down menu is located so that the user is able to type the other option they didn't find in the current selection of colours.

How would I be able to achieve this?

```
import React, { Fragment} from 'react';
import { StyledSection, StyledSectionColLeft, StyledSectionCol } from '../../../common/theme/cssStyledColumns';
import { Textarea, Select, Input, MandatoryInfo } from '../../../common/form';

const ApplianceDetails = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <h2>Appliance details</h2>
    <MandatoryInfo />
    <StyledSection>
      <StyledSectionColLeft>
        <Select name="colour" label="Colour *">
          <option value="">-Select-</option>
          <option value="Vokera">Blue</option>
          <option value="Warmflow">Red</option>
          <option value="Worcester">Yellow</option>
          <option onClick={console.log('Click happened')} value="Other">Other</option>
        </Select>
        <Input name="model" label="Model *" />
      </StyledSectionColLeft>
      <StyledSectionCol>
        <Input name="location" label="Location *" />
      </StyledSectionCol>
    </StyledSection>
  </Fragment>
);

export default ApplianceDetails;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editable 'Select' element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141357/editable-select-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a class on an `input`/`textarea` based on the value of `select`. Like this:

```
<Select value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleSelect} name="colour" label="Colour *">
  <option value="">-Select-</option>
  <option value="Vokera">Blue</option>
  <option value="Warmflow">Red</option>
  <option value="Worcester">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</Select>

// Or textarea
<input type="text" value="" name=" className={this.state.selectedOption !== 'Other'?"hidden":""}/>
```

This adds a class of `hidden` to your input. Now you can use `.hidden{ diplay:none; }`

And this function will handle change of your values:

```
handleSelect(evt){
  this.setState({
    selectedOption: evt.target.value
  })
}
```

Comment: My console in the browser (Google Chrome) is displaying the following error:`Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"`

So I changed your syntax and wrote:
`handleSelect = (evt) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedOption: evt.target.value
  })
}`

but it didn't work and I'm getting the following error:
`'handleSelect' is not defined  no-undef`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you added `this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, I did. I added the `this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);` part inside my `onChange` event inside my select tag and the first error I get is the classic `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"` point out the semicolon. I remove the semicolon and I get the following:
`Line 69:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"`
`> 69 | handleSelect(evt){`
`|                  ^`

I think it's caused by a syntax error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Edit: The first time, the console is pointing out the semicolon and the second time it's pointing out the parenthesis just after the `handleSelect(evt)` name of the function